# Laravel 7 - migrate:refresh got access denied

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I start to work on a `laravel` project that start by colleage. once I pulled down the git I want to do migration:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Immediately I got an error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.19.0.1'
> (using password: NO) (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE
> TABLE')

which seems odd because I checked all my `config/database.php`, `.env`, all point to `127.0.0.1` for `mysql` and not sure where `172.19.0.1` come from.

How can I debug this?

Comment: Maybe Your colleage accedentally pushed cached config to git too. It's just a guess but if it's true than `php artisan cache:clear` might help.

Comment: Tried that. still not working.

Comment: It is not ```cache:clear``` you need, it is ```config:clear```. Please see my answer to a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62820384/laravel-environment-variableswithout-default-value-passed-in-method-not-workin/62820726#62820726

Comment: And did you search in your project for `172.19.0.1`?

Comment: I found out the issue. It seems like some cache project that cannot be clear by config:clear or cache:clear. I have to literally go to delete the file in config/cache/ folder to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your database, you have permissions issue for the database user.

Grant permissions for your db user `root`.

Execute the below command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'root'@'172.19.0.1';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```