# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `permissions`)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7

I upload my project on C-panel and set my connection for database in my **env** file, it was ok for me with the same settings, but now i don't know why it's happening, this is error :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * 
from `permissions`)
```

And this is my **env** file settings for database :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=thermota_db
DB_USERNAME=thermota_user
DB_PASSWORD= { my password }
```

i don't know this permissions in error, is my permissions_table ?

and why error for this table ?

Comment: nothing in that error lines up with your env file. Make sure its called .env . The error says the supplied user is root with no password ..

Comment: It says "using password: NO" maybe put your password in quotes to avoid errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple reasons can be the cause.

1. This can happen when the server has already been started before  updating database details on your .ENV file.
2. It could also be from inputting wrong database authentication details.

Solution

1. Restart the server anytime you update values on your .ENV file.
2. Ensure you use the correct authentication details or better still create a new database user.

Comment: how can i reset my server, my project uploaded on c-panel

Comment: and im 100% sure about authentication

Comment: you need to enable all privileges for this user from your Cpanel.

Comment: yes project work fine offline, all privileges are enabled for user

Answer (score 2):

Run this command:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

You are trying to use a different user that means that your root value is not used.

You need to cache your env field to use the values in it. That goes for every change you make as well.

Comment: This is only true if you have config cache enabled. You can just as easily disable config cache for local development.

Comment: Well 99% of this kind of problems i've see they were coming because the app was not reading the env file. Also laravel needs to set's the cache so it can use the env

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62820384/laravel-environment-variableswithout-default-value-passed-in-method-not-workin/62820726#62820726

Comment: I don't see why to remove cache and how is that relevant to the question

Comment: Your answer ```php artisan optimize``` is just an alias for ```php artisan config:clear``` ```php artisan config:cache``` ```php artisan route:clear```  ```php artisan route:cache``` the point of my comment is that telling people blindly to start using this command is not always correct. Ie) caching on local development environment.

Comment: What you are saying is that he may want to keep his routes cleared and config his cache. Well that's unlikely in my opinion but config:cache is tackling specific that issue so i will change my answer.

Comment: how can i run php artisan config:cache? should i run in my phpstorm and upload again ?

Comment: open a terminal, go to your project and run the command. You can open a normal terminal or one in php storm. as long as you are in the project folder you will be able to run artisan commands

Comment: i know, but my project is now on server c-panel, can i run this commond on cpanel or i have to run this commond in my local, and upload project again ?

Comment: You have to run it in the environment you need. So if you are in production then you have to ssh to your server or access it in general and run it there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218694/discussion-between-waltun-and-pr1nc3).

Answer (score 1):

if ur on online server do the following steps :

```
1 - locate to : /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php
2 - add thoes line of code on the begining of this function :  createConnection($dsn, array $config, array $options)
3 - code to add : \Artisan::call('config:cache');
4 - refresh ur home page 
5 - remove the "\Artisan::call('config:cache');" line code
6 - enjoye ^^
```

Comment: It'd be nice if you could provide more information on how this solves the question or how the output of that route helps solving it.

Comment: yesterday i did have the same probleme and i put that route on my web.php i called it on my browser after a while i checked home page so it was working.

Comment: This command clears the cache and re-caches the configuration. This behavior indicates that the configuration was cached before and therefore changes to the configuration didn't come to effect until you cleared your cache.

Comment: All what i know that it has worked for me so its prety cool thats why i shared it her ^^

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I couldn't run `config:cache` artisan command even with
`Artisan::call('config:cache');`.

So I done this and solved my issue:

`artisan config:cache` caches all files from `/config` into a single array that it stores. It then reads all config variables from that array and ignores anything in `.env` or the `/config` files until you recach them. That's why it still works after deleting `.env`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#configuration-caching

If you don't have ssh access to your live server, you'd just need to delete the `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file, which is the cache file `config:cache` generates.